# Genomics Analysis after Blast

Tags: linux, shell

This is how my Data look like, a results obtained after blast-p.
I have tried this command but it is not providing my desired outputs.

```
cat out_uniprot-proteome%3AUP000001415.fasta |grep -P -B5 'Identities = \d+/\d+\s\(([7-9]\d|100)%'


Query= sp|Q835H3|MUTS2_ENTFA Endonuclease MutS2 OS=Enterococcus faecalis
(strain ATCC 700802 / V583) OX=226185 GN=mutS2 PE=3 SV=1

Length=788
                                                                      Score     E
Sequences producing significant alignments:                          (Bits)  Value

  sp|O15457|MSH4_HUMAN MutS protein homolog 4 OS=Homo sapiens OX=...  109     8e-24
  tr|A8K1E1|A8K1E1_HUMAN cDNA FLJ75589, highly similar to Homo sa...  107     4e-23
  sp|P20585|MSH3_HUMAN DNA mismatch repair protein Msh3 OS=Homo s...  107     4e-23
  tr|B4DSB9|B4DSB9_HUMAN cDNA FLJ51069, highly similar to DNA mis...  102     1e-21
  tr|B4DL39|B4DL39_HUMAN cDNA FLJ57316, highly similar to DNA mis...  102     1e-21
  tr|A0A2R8YFH0|A0A2R8YFH0_HUMAN DNA mismatch repair protein OS=H...  101     3e-21
  tr|A0A2R8Y6P0|A0A2R8Y6P0_HUMAN DNA mismatch repair protein OS=H...  101     3e-21
  tr|B4DN49|B4DN49_HUMAN DNA mismatch repair protein OS=Homo sapi...  101     3e-21
  tr|E9PHA6|E9PHA6_HUMAN DNA mismatch repair protein OS=Homo sapi...  101     3e-21
  sp|P43246|MSH2_HUMAN DNA mismatch repair protein Msh2 OS=Homo s...  101     3e-21
  tr|Q53GS1|Q53GS1_HUMAN DNA mismatch repair protein (Fragment) O...  101     3e-21
  tr|A0A2R8YG02|A0A2R8YG02_HUMAN DNA mismatch repair protein OS=H...  101     3e-21
  tr|Q53FK0|Q53FK0_HUMAN DNA mismatch repair protein (Fragment) O...  100     6e-21
  tr|B4DZX3|B4DZX3_HUMAN cDNA FLJ54211, highly similar to MutS pr...  90.1    5e-18
  tr|A0A0G2JJ70|A0A0G2JJ70_HUMAN MSH5-SAPCD1 readthrough (NMD can...  89.7    5e-18
  tr|A2ABF0|A2ABF0_HUMAN cDNA FLJ39914 fis, clone SPLEN2018732, h...  89.7    5e-18
  tr|Q9UFG2|Q9UFG2_HUMAN Uncharacterized protein DKFZp434C1615 (F...  87.0    6e-18
  tr|H0YF11|H0YF11_HUMAN MSH5-SAPCD1 readthrough (NMD candidate) ...  87.0    6e-18

> sp|O15457|MSH4_HUMAN MutS protein homolog 4 OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 
GN=MSH4 PE=1 SV=2
Length=936

 Score = 109 bits (273),  Expect = 8e-24, Method: Compositional matrix adjust.
 Identities = 71/228 (31%), Positives = 118/228 (52%), Gaps = 8/228 (4%)



> tr|Q0QEN7|Q0QEN7_HUMAN ATP synthase subunit beta (Fragment) OS=Homo 
sapiens OX=9606 GN=ATP5B PE=2 SV=1
Length=445

 Score = 590 bits (1522),  Expect = 0.0, Method: Compositional matrix adjust.
 Identities = 300/448 (67%), Positives = 357/448 (80%), Gaps = 12/448 (3%)
--
Query  423  SYVPVAETVRGFKEILEGKHDNLPEEAF  450
              VP+ ET++GF++IL G++D+LPE+AF
Sbjct  416  KLVPLKETIKGFQQILAGEYDHLPEQAF  443


> tr|H0YH81|H0YH81_HUMAN ATP synthase subunit beta (Fragment) OS=Homo 
sapiens OX=9606 GN=ATP5F1B PE=1 SV=1
Length=362

 Score = 459 bits (1182),  Expect = 1e-158, Method: Compositional matrix adjust.
 Identities = 228/327 (70%), Positives = 265/327 (81%), Gaps = 7/327 (2%)
--
Query  342  DPLASSSSALAPEIVGEEHYEVATEVQ  368
            DPL S+S  + P IVG EHY+VA  VQ
Sbjct  336  DPLDSTSRIMDPNIVGSEHYDVARGVQ  362


> tr|F8W0P7|F8W0P7_HUMAN ATP synthase subunit beta, mitochondrial 
(Fragment) OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=ATP5F1B PE=1 SV=2
Length=270

 Score = 281 bits (720),  Expect = 1e-90, Method: Compositional matrix adjust.
 Identities = 137/168 (82%), Positives = 151/168 (90%), Gaps = 6/168 (4%)
--
Query  265  LGRMPSAVGYQPTLATEMGQLQERITSTKKGSITSIQAIYVPADDYTD  312
            LGR+PSAVGYQPTLAT+MG +QERIT+TKKGSITS+QAIYVPADD TD
Sbjct  223  LGRIPSAVGYQPTLATDMGTMQERITTTKKGSITSVQAIYVPADDLTD  270
```

Output i want is:

```
Query= sp|Q835H3|MUTS2_ENTFA Endonuclease MutS2 OS=Enterococcus faecalis
(strain ATCC 700802 / V583) OX=226185 GN=mutS2 PE=3 SV=1

> tr|H0YH81|H0YH81_HUMAN ATP synthase subunit beta (Fragment) OS=Homo 
sapiens OX=9606 GN=ATP5F1B PE=1 SV=1
Length=362

 Score = 459 bits (1182),  Expect = 1e-158, Method: Compositional matrix adjust.
 Identities = 228/327 (70%), Positives = 265/327 (81%), Gaps = 7/327 (2%)

> tr|F8W0P7|F8W0P7_HUMAN ATP synthase subunit beta, mitochondrial 
(Fragment) OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=ATP5F1B PE=1 SV=2
Length=270

 Score = 281 bits (720),  Expect = 1e-90, Method: Compositional matrix adjust.
 Identities = 137/168 (82%), Positives = 151/168 (90%), Gaps = 6/168 (4%)
```

I want the Query of the respective strains having Identities 70% or greater.

Comment: How are the data formatted? Is there any start/stop seqence of characters?  Which lines? How is "the Query" "respective" to the "strains"? What do you mean by "respective", ie. how to find a query having a strain? Which line is a strain? So many questions.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: A related question I have is, how did this question get past the new question wizard? What is not clear or confusing about using the wizard?